# How do I make a table show a vertical scroll bar without explicitly setting the height?

Tags: html, css

I have some code that displays a table. If the browser width is reduced such that the table is wider than it, a scroll bar appears for the table rather than the browser. This works the way I want it to. However, when I reduce the height of the browser window the scroll bar appears on the browser rather than on the table.

How do I get the scroll bar to appear on the table?

If I set the height of the div containing the table to a set value (e.g. height: 100px;) then the scroll bar appears as expected. I don't want to have to do this though. I just want the table to use up all the vertical space on the screen as required and once it overflows, for a scroll bar to appear on the table.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukfwqLat/8/) and here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pivot Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-content">

    <div id="field-selection-area">
        <ul class="no-text-selection">
            <li draggable="true">Period</li>
            <li draggable="true">Trade ID</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="field-table-area">
        <div id="field-config-area">
            <div id="row-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
                Drop Row Fields Here
            </div>
            <div id="column-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
                Drop Column Fields Here
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="table-area">
            <table>
                <tr><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td><td>18.0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.3</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
#main-content{
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#field-selection-area{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: 1px darkgrey solid;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

#field-selection-area ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}

#field-selection-area ul li{
    padding: 4px;
}

#field-table-area{
    border-right: 1px darkgrey solid;
    border-bottom: 1px darkgrey solid;
}

.field-area {
    border-top: 1px darkgrey solid;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

#table-area{
    border-top: 1px darkgrey solid;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
}

#table-area table td{
    border: 1px darkgrey solid;
}
```

I hope I have explained it well enough.

Comment: You can't without explicitly setting the height of the table wrapper.  If the height of the table exceeds the window screen size, the whole page is going to scroll, that's just the way it works.

Comment: but it works with the width, is there no way I can replicate that with the height?

Comment: Can you not just set `overflow-y:scroll;` on the element you want to show a scrollbar. (it will be disabled on some element heights, but still show)

Comment: When I do that the scrollbar is shown but it never gets enabled, the scrollbar on the browser appears instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this in the end so putting the code here in case anyone else needs it.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#field-table-area {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.field-area {
  border-bottom: 1px darkgrey solid;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
.flexbox-item-grow {
  flex: 1;
  /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
}
#field-selection-area {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  overflow: auto;
  border-right: 1px darkgrey solid;
}
#field-selection-area ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
}
#field-selection-area ul li {
  padding: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#field-selection-area ul li:hover {
  border: 1px darkgrey solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 230, 241);
}
#table-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#table-holder {
  overflow: auto;
}
#table-holder table td {
  border: 1px darkgrey solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pivot Web</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main-content">
    <div id="field-selection-area">
      <ul class="no-text-selection">
        <li draggable="true">Period</li>
        <li draggable="true">Market</li>
        <li draggable="true">Trade ID</li>
        <li draggable="true">Something</li>
        <li draggable="true">Something Space</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="field-table-area" class="flexbox-item-grow">
      <div id="field-config-area">
        <div id="filter-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
          Drop Filter Fields Here
        </div>

        <div id="row-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
          Drop Row Fields Here
        </div>

        <div id="column-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
          Drop Column Fields Here
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="table-area" class="flexbox-item-grow">
        <div id="table-holder" class="flexbox-item-grow">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
              <td>18.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
              <td>5.3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This allows just the table to scroll when it is either wider or higher than the browser window.

The screen shot shows it in this state:

[image: Scrolling Table]

Comment: @MikeGates it would be nice to get it working in all browsers but I'm only targeting chrome. If you manage to get it working in firefox please post here

Answer (score 0):

Set the height relative to the viewport.

```
#table-area {max-height: 100vh;}
```

Alternatively you can size the entire body based on the viewport, split it into subsections with [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), which will automatically size themselves according to the available space and the demands of their content and then set `overflow:auto` just on the flexbox container for the table.
That'll give the page more of a "desktop application" feel where you have some fixed UI elements around around a scrollable subsection containing the bulk data.

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work because I don't want the table-area to take up the full height of the viewport because there are other divs above it that take up space. I'll try and understand and test your second suggestion but you are correct in saying I would like a desktop application feel. I'm coming at this from a long time swing developer.

Comment: you are obviously free to pick a value less than 100. But flexboxes will avoid manually calculating the dimensions. If you come from swing then flexboxes are basically like `BoxLayout` or `FlowLayout`, depending on whether wrapping is turned on or not. Nesting them should allow you to get some basic grid.